# Tell compiler that returning true from a function means that SDK version has been checked and is at least X

Tags: android

I've a setup class with a function like following:

```
object Setup {
    fun USE_WINDOW_INSETS(): Boolean = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R
}
```

Can I somehow tell the compiler, that `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` is greater than `R` if this function returns true? I want to avoid code with redundant information like following:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && SetupProvider.get().USE_WINDOW_INSETS())
{
    // compiler knows sdk version is at least R
}
```

I know I can make the function only callable from sdk version `P` or higher by annotating it with  `@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)` but this is not what I want, the function should be callable from every sdk version directly.

**What I want**

```
if (SetupProvider.get().USE_WINDOW_INSETS())
{
    // compiler SHOULD know now that sdk version is at least R
}
else
{
    // compiler SHOULD know that sdk version is lower than R
}
```

Comment: almost seems like you want something like smart cast from the compiler, in a bit of a weird way, but not sure if this would be possible, but very interesting regardless. let's hope you get an answer